# Move everything in state down the hierarchy

Tags: terraform

I'm refactoring some code in terraform and would like to move everything into a module.
Couldn't find any examples of terraform state mv doing that, is it possible?
Example of what I mean, let's say I have

```
aws_iam_role.my_role
aws_iam_role.my_second_role
aws_iam_role.my_third_role
```

and many other resources (with other resource types)
I would like to introduce module that would contain everything in current directory and have it looking like this

```
aws_iam_role.module.my_module.my_role
aws_iam_role.module.my_module.my_second_role
aws_iam_role.module.my_module.my_third_role
```

with one terraform command.

Answer (score 2):

#### Attention: manipulating the terraform state can always lead to unintended destruction of resources and data. So better have a backup ready and at least another pair of eyes.

**Also better block others from applying changes and stop any CI that applies changes.**

---

That said:

Note: The new address will be `module.my-module.*` not `aws_*.module.my-module.*`

#### Option A: (your initial idea)

I can't help you with providing an easy way of manipulating the state in an automated way but just to move resource by resource using `terraform state mv`.
(described here: https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/state/mv.html#example-move-a-resource-into-a-module)

```sh
terraform state mv 'aws_iam_role.my_role'        'module.my_module.aws_iam_role.my_role'
terraform state mv 'aws_iam_role.my_second_role' 'module.my_module.aws_iam_role.my_second_role'
terraform state mv 'aws_iam_role.my_third_role'  'module.my_module.aws_iam_role.my_third_role'
```

#### Option B: (not recommended)

If you know what you do you can of course try to manually manipulate the statefile and do a search&replace. If you feel unsure about this, better don't do it.

In addition, make sure nobody else is deploying while you are manipulating the state and moving resources around, as this can lead to unexpected destruction of resources. Reason: Your state file and git repository will most likely be out of sync during this operation.

#### Option C: (safer way)

My recommendation for bigger changes like this:
A slightly safer way is to create a new statefile for the moduled-version. You would need to import all resources into the moduled-version using `terraform import` once done and happy, you can just deprecate the old state and just continue to use the new one.

If you notice you have too many resources already you can use the opportunity to also split your infrastructure into smaller modules.